# Best way to avoid redrawing an entire maze?

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, maze

I'm working on a project for maze generation using Java, swing, and Java2D. I'm fairly new to Java2D so please excuse me if this question is newbish.

Basically, I have a successfully generated maze. I wish to draw this maze on a custom JPanel that I've set up and properly overridden PaintComponent on. The problem I have now is I currently have the ability to draw the maze, but every time I repaint it disappears. I've solved this by having it redraw the maze every time repaint() is called but this seems horribly inefficient. Since the maze doesn't change why should I have to redraw it?

So my question is this: is there any way to "cache" the drawing of the maze so I don't have to waste cycles redrawing it every time? I can see redrawing it every time for exceptionally large mazes being a major source of slow downs.

Thank you!

Comment: If drawing in `paintComponent` with first calling `super.PaintComponent` double buffering should not give paint effects. Not much creation or other costly operations while drawing, no `repaint` in paintComponent. Less repaints, `repaint(50L)` is nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the maze to a BufferedImage. Then in your paintComponent() method just paint the BufferedImage. Swing will determine whether the entire maze or just parts of it need to be repainted.

For an example painting onto a BufferedImage see the `DrawOnImage` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

Answer (score 0):

If the maze never changes, you can initially draw it into a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).  You can use your same code you wrote for overriding `paintComponent` by creating a BufferedImage and calling `image.createGraphics()` on it to get a `Graphics2D` object.  Any painting you do to the `Graphics2D` object returned from `createGraphics()` is added to the `BufferedImage`.  You may have to extract your previous drawing code just for the maze into its own function which takes a `Graphics2D` object and draws to it.

Once you have your maze drawn into the `BufferedImage`, you can use any of the `drawImage()` functions in `Graphics` or `Graphics2D`.  This avoids having to redraw the maze: now you are just drawing the already rendered image.